# C++: Why would a regular function run faster than Inline function?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I was doing a speed experiment and timed an inline function vs a regular function and I repeatedly get better timing on the regular function.  Can you please take a look at the code and help me figure out why this is being that inlining is supposed to improve speed.

Thanks

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "time.h"

inline int getMaxInline( int x, int y )
{
    return ( x > y ) ? x : y;
}

int getMaxRegular( int, int );


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    clock_t inlineStart;
    clock_t inlineFinish;
    clock_t regularStart;
    clock_t regularFinish;

    inlineStart = clock();
    std::cout<<"inline max of 20 and 10 = "<<getMaxInline( 10, 20 )<<std::endl;
    inlineFinish = clock();


    std::cout<<"Time elapsed for inline = "<<(double(inlineFinish - inlineStart)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC)<<std::endl;


    regularStart = clock();
    std::cout<<"regular max of 20 and 10 = "<<getMaxRegular( 20, 10 )<<std::endl;
    regularFinish = clock();

    std::cout<<"Time elapsed for regular = "<<(double(regularFinish - regularStart)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC)<<std::endl;

    return 0;
}


int getMaxRegular( int x, int y )
{
    return ( x > y ) ? x : y;
}
```

My last 3 tests ran:

inline = 0.042
regular = 0.003

inline = 0.004
regular = 0.002

inline = 0.006
regular = 0.002

Any insights?

Thanks

Comment: the output you show is not the output of the code.  your function getMaxRegular is not shown.  how do we know it's not rigged?  also, inline is a suggestion, not command.  you need to verify that it is, in fact, inlined by the compiler.

Comment: The timing method is also completely bogus.

Comment: Also clock: Returns the processor time consumed by the program.  That's not the real run time...  and look at your #s.  they're so small that you're probably just measuring noise.  there are so many things wrong with this post.

Comment: The output of the result takes thousands of times longer than the functions you're calling. Any possible difference between your functions will be in nanoseconds, not milliseconds.

Comment: Apologies everybody I did a copy/paste and apparently didn't put in the getMaxRegular function.  I've edited the post to include it.  Also please can you suggest better timing methods if mine is wrong or how to verify that the compiler indeed inlined. I'm am only asking cause I don't know guys.

Comment: @thang: You _want_ the processor time consumed by the program. Why would you measure wall time, which includes everything else your computer is doing?

Comment: @SilverBackApe: Well did you perform any _research_ on how to make useful benchmarks? There is plenty of information out there on doing so.

Comment: @SilverBackApe: In order to more or less reliably time function's performance you have to call it millions of times between time measurements and you have to do it with minimal overhead. What you do now does not measure anything related to these functions' performance.

Answer (score 2):

Bluntly, your program isn't constructed even remotely like the way programs that accurately measure the performance of code are constructed. In the call to the inline function, all the output code is not hot in the CPU code and branch prediction caches. In your call to the non-inline function, it is. This will completely dominate any microscopic differences due to avoiding a single call/return operation.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between an `inline` function and one that isn't inlined depends 100% on the compiler and the optimization settings.

The keyword `inline` is a suggestion to the compiler.  It is allowed to ignore the recommendation.

Given two equal functions, the only difference between an `inline` function and a non-inline function should be the call and return overhead.  This is at least 2 processor instructions, call and return.  Let's assume the call and return instructions take 1 ms each (which is very, very, slow).  You have saved 2 milliseconds by inlining.  Waiting for User I/O is in terms of seconds.  File I/O is usually in terms of milliseconds.  So, is that 2 milliseconds significant?  In the general case, no.

But wait, that is not all you gain.  By removing an extra call, in some processors you prevent the instruction cache from being reloaded.  That can save you some huge nanoseconds.  Again, is it significant?  Probably not.

On the other side of the coin, you have spent a lot of development time to profile and experiment with this.  That time you could be spending making your program more robust and correct.  Your kind of optimization -inlining - is called a micro-optimization.  Usually these optimizations have a very low Return On Investment.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the clock is going to be granular enough to give you accurate numbers for such a small function. Instead, time how long a loop takes to call each function like ten thousand or one hundred thousand times, and then divide your resulting time by the call count to get a more accurate measurement. Try to pick a loop count that would get each loop to run for one to ten seconds.

Also, don't print things while you're timing it. Then you're timing the I/O and not just the function call. I/O likely takes much longer in this case than your actual function.

Comment: Also: disable any CPU frequency scaling before running the test. Also: run the test into perf or callgrind or vtune to get detailed timing info. Also: any modern compiler with LTO will optimize that out.